# Remove entity from post before binding it

Tags: symfony

Let's say I have a main form (foo entity form) where I have an embedded form (bar entity embedded form).
Let's also say that foo - 1/many - bar (of course).

Now, I want to display all possible bar entities in the system, even if they aren't associated with foo. So before bind form with foo entity, I usually do some query, extract data and, if bar isn't already associated with foo, associate it (basically i create some "virtual" association that haven't to be persisted under certain circumstance. I can't use symfony2 native method as I need to handle some attributes and Symfony2 don't let me do that)

All works like a charm. Now I added to bar form a non-mapped field that should help me to know whenever to save or not the association.

Into controller I check for the presence of this field and if not, I artificially unset the index of the collection from request object. When I dump the request all is good (embedded elements without flag aren't there anymore).

## BUT

When I bind request object to entity, all embedded form elements are still there. This is driving me totally cray.

### Code example

(I will not paste entity code as the issue is not there. I will not paste form code also)

```
public function createAction()
{
  $foo = new Foo();
  $foo_form = $this->createForm(new FooType(), $foo);
  if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $parameter_array = $request->request->all();
    $bar_array = $parameter_array['foo']['bar'];
    //If I dump here, of course, all bar are setted
    foreach ($bar_array as $index => $bar) {
      if (!isset($bar['associate'])) { //this is the flag 
        unset($parameter_array['foo']['bar'][$index]);
      }
    }
    $request->request->replace($parameter_array);
    //If i dump $request->request->all(); all non-flagged bar are gone
    $foo_form->bind($request);
    $foo->getBars(); //If I dump this all bar(s) are still there (even the not-flagged ones)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround. As I can't controller - or at least it seems I cannot - directly parameter bag when entities are involved, I've simply act upon object *after* form and object are binded.

My code is now this

```
public function createAction()
{
  $foo = new Foo();
  $foo_form = $this->createForm(new FooType(), $foo);

  if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $foo_form->bind($request);
    if ($foo_form->isValid()) {
      $parameter_array = $request->request->all();
      if (isset($parameter_array['foo']['bar'])) {
        $bars = $foo->getBars();
        $bar_array = $parameter_array['foo']['bar'];
        foreach ($bar_array as $index => $bar) { //Of course here
          if (!isset($bar['associate'])) { // I can use array_filter
            $bars->remove($index); // or something similar. Is just more readable that way for this answer
          }
        }
        $foo->setBars($bars);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better solution?